# Python: why does regex compiled with re.IGNORECASE drop first chars?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have the following regex in python to parse listings in text:

```
re.compile('(.*,?) and (.*)')
```

Everything works as expected, except when the re is compiled with the `re.IGNORECASE` flag, then the first two chars are not returned.

Output from re group 1 when compiled **without** the IGNORECASE flag:

```
the 1689 London Baptist Confession of Faith , 1742 Philadelphia Baptist Confession , the 1833 New Hampshire Baptist Confession of Faith , the Southern Baptist Convention 's Baptist Faith and Message ,
```

Output from re group 1 when compiled **with** the IGNORECASE flag:

```
e 1689 London Baptist Confession of Faith , 1742 Philadelphia Baptist Confession , the 1833 New Hampshire Baptist Confession of Faith , the Southern Baptist Convention 's Baptist Faith and Message ,
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) regarding the flag states:

> Perform case-insensitive matching; expressions like [A-Z] will match lowercase letters, too. This is not affected by the current locale. To get this effect on non-ASCII Unicode characters such as ü and Ü, add the UNICODE flag.

So no hint regarding this behaviour, what could explain it or am I missing something obvious here?
EDIT: As requested in the comments, the full code example (Python 3.6.5):

```
listing_re = re.compile('(.*,?) and (.*)')
def parse_listing(txt):
    listing_search = listing_re.search(txt, re.IGNORECASE)
    if listing_search:
        seperated_by_comma = listing_search.group(1)    # listing of expressions, seperated by ','
        parts = seperated_by_comma.split(',')           # split string at ','
        parts.append(listing_search.group(2))           # append the single expression after 'and'
        return [x.strip() for x in parts if x.strip()]  # return list of stripped exressions
    return list()

print(parse_listing("the 1689 London Baptist Confession of Faith , 1742 Philadelphia Baptist Confession , the 1833 New Hampshire Baptist Confession of Faith , the Southern Baptist Convention 's Baptist Faith and Message , and written church covenants"))
```

Code above returns wrong result, removing the re.IGNORECASE flag returns the correct result.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Python 3.4 - 3.7. Please provide full code that shows this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that you're passing the `re.IGNORECASE` flag in the wrong place. Since `listing_re` is a compiled regex, `listing_re.search` has a signature like this ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.search)):

> **Pattern.search(string[, pos[, endpos]])**
>
> [...]
>
> The optional second parameter pos gives an index in the string where the search is to start; it defaults to 0. This is not completely equivalent to slicing the string; the '^' pattern character matches at the real beginning of the string and at positions just after a newline, but not necessarily at the index where the search is to start.

As you can see, you've passed `re.IGNORECASE` as the value of the `pos` parameter. Since `re.IGNORECASE` happens to have a value of 2, you end up skipping the first 2 characters.

```
>>> re.IGNORECASE
<RegexFlag.IGNORECASE: 2>
```

---

The correct usage would be to pass the flags to [`re.compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile):

```
listing_re = re.compile('(.*,?) and (.*)', re.IGNORECASE)
```