# Python compiled regex - search with ignorecase

Tags: python, regex

Am I doing something wrong, or is the following behavior expected when searching a compiled regex in Python with the IGNORECASE flag?  The strange behavior is that it appears I must define `IGNORECASE` when compiling a regex, but I cannot use the IGNORECASE flag when searching a compiled regex.

```py
import re

regex_string = "test"

assert re.search(regex_string, "test")
assert re.search(regex_string, "TEST", re.IGNORECASE)

regex = re.compile(regex_string, re.IGNORECASE)
assert regex.search("test")
assert regex.search("TEST")
#assert regex.search("TEST", re.IGNORECASE) # appears logical but fails

regex2 = re.compile(regex_string)
assert regex2.search("test")
#assert regex2.search("TEST", re.IGNORECASE) # appears logical but fails
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: why does regex compiled with re.IGNORECASE drop first chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52026997/python-why-does-regex-compiled-with-re-ignorecase-drop-first-chars)

Comment: May be a duplicate of this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500864/case-insensitive-regular-expression-without-re-compile

Comment: note: you create the variable `regex2` but don't use it at all, you still call `regex.search()`

Comment: @truth thanks - corrected. About the duplicate question - yeah I suppose the answers to both questions are the same. This question might be useful to highlight the misuse in a simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation for the python `re` module:

- re.search(pattern, string, flags=0) allows flags as an optional argument. [3.7 documentation link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search)
- Pattern.search(string[, pos[, endpos]]) does not. The compiled pattern must have been compiled with any settings you wanted to apply. [3.7 documentation link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-objects)

Comment: Thanks - missed that in the docs.  As an inexperienced Python user I mistakenly presumed the compiler would complain about the invalid argument.