# First two characters of a string are being cut off when i match text with a regular expression and fetch the matched text

Tags: python, regex

I wrote a piece of code that simply asks for the user's name and returns it in a formatted string using a regex. I'm not too sure what i am doing wrong. I've looked at the documentation for the module i'm using, **re**, and i didn't find anything. I've also checked my textbook i'm learning from and failed to find anything.

```
import re

p = re.compile('(?P<word>[a-zA-Z]+)')

print('Hi. Whats your name?')

userin = input()

match = p.search(userin, re.IGNORECASE)
name = match.group('word')

print('Hi {} im Dad Bot!'.format(name))
```

For example, if i input *Bobby* it returns "*Hi bby im Dad Bot!*"

Is it possible that my problem is with the **re** module or is it something wrong with my regex **(?P[a-zA-Z]+)**

Comment: Remove `re.IGNORECASE`, `match.search` second argument is `pos`, not `flags`

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/52027191/10987432